# If null use other variable in one line in PHP

Tags: php

Is there in PHP something similar to JavaScript's:

```
alert(test || 'Hello');
```

So, when test is undefined or null we'll see Hello, otherwise - we'll see the value of test.

I tried similar syntax in PHP but it doesn't seem to be working right... Also I've got no idea how to google this problem..

thanks

**Edit**

I should probably add that I wanted to use it inside an array:

```
$arr = array($one || 'one?', $two || 'two?'); //This is wrong
```

But indeed, I can use the inline '? :' if statement here as well, thanks.

```
$arr = array(is_null($one) ? "one?" : $one, is_null($two) ? "two ?" : $two); //OK
```

Comment: If you want to create an array with more than 3 elements like this, have a look at my answer to save yourself a lot ternary operators ;)

Comment: well, yeah, obviously I'd put it in some sort of utility function ;) thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

See @Yamiko's answer below for a PHP7 solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/29217577/140413

```php
 echo (!$test) ? 'hello' : $test;
```

Or you can be a little more robust and do this

```php
echo isset($test) ? $test : 'hello';
```

Comment: Why check against !$test and not just do $test ? $test : 'hello'; instead?

Comment: Well he stated if $test was undefined or null he wanted to see 'Hello', if the value of $test was int(0) he'd still see hello even though it's set and not null because php interprets 0 as false unless you're using ===.  So just to be safe he should check to see if $test is set and not null.  At least that was my logic.

Comment: I understand but your resolution is very confusing :( . It should not be a accepted answer according to "If null use other variable in one line in PHP". The answer of @yamiko is very simple as well as  useful.l

Comment: The `|| is_null()` is redundant here, `isset($var)` returns false if `$var` is null

Answer (score 82):

From PHP 7 onwards you can use something called a [coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary#vote) which does exactly what you want without the E_NOTICE that `?:` triggers.

To use it you use `??` which will check if the value on the left is set and not null.

```
$arr = array($one ?? 'one?', $two ?? 'two?');
```

Answer (score 81):

you can do `echo $test ?: 'hello';`

This will echo `$test` if it is true and `'hello'` otherwise.

**Note** it will throw a notice or strict error if `$test` is not set but...

This shouldn't be a problem since most servers are set to ignore these errors. Most frameworks have code that triggers these errors.

---

**Edit:**  This is a classic [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), but with the middle part left out. Available since PHP 5.3.

```php
echo $test ? $test : 'hello'; // this is the same
echo $test ?: 'hello';        // as this one
```

This only checks for the truthiness of the first variable and not if it is undefined, in which case it triggers the `E_NOTICE` error. For the latter, check the PHP7 answer below (soon hopefully above).

Comment: I agree but major libraries and plugins for them trigger them all the time so they are usually ignored in production. Also this type of error is E_NOTICE which is something that is safe to ignore. I personally don't like triggering any kind of error including E_NOTICE but this type of error is more about best practices than an actual error that needs to be fixed

Comment: Also I know premature optimization is bad and all but triggering a notice causes the error handling function (whether PHP's default or a custom one) to be called even if that function ends up ignoring the error due to your error_reporting setting, and that can be slow especially if you do it within a loop.

Comment: What's the name of this ?: operator? Can someone link to the docs?

Comment: @inafalcao It is classic [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), but with the middle part left out. So it kind of makes it a shorthand ternary operator. Available since PHP 5.3.

Comment: @dboris Thank you!

Comment: Aka [the elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) :D

Comment: Neat, I never knew about this.  You could say `?:` is to `?` as `+=` is to `=`... kinda.

Answer (score 11):

As per the latest version use this for the shorthand

```
$var = $value ?? "secondvalue";
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for this answer. Seems that the null-coalescing operator was added in PHP 7. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce

Comment: For PHP >7 this is definitely the cleanest way to do it!

Answer (score 6):

One-liner. Super readable, works for regular variables, arrays and objects.

```
// standard variable string
$result = @$var_str ?: "default";

// missing array element
$result = @$var_arr["missing"] ?: "default";

// missing object member
$result = @$var_obj->missing ?: "default";
```

See it in action: [Php Sandbox Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e345ee3fb8f66705873e596edaee13ebcc62a5da)

Answer (score 5):

I'm very surprised this isn't suggested in the other answers:

```
echo isset($test) ? $test : 'hello';
```

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) `isset($var)` will return **false** if `$var` doesn't exist **or is set to null**.

The null coalesce operator from PHP 7 onwards, described by @Yamiko, is a syntax shortcut for the above.

In this case:

```
echo $test ?? 'hello';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array this way, [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) provides a more concise way to do this (depending on the number of elements in the array):

```
function defined_map($value, $default) {
    return (!isset($value) || is_null($value)) ? $default : $value;
    // or return $value ? $default : $value;
}

$values = array($one, $two);
$defaults = array('one', 'two');

$values = array_map('defined_map', $values, $defaults);
```

Just make sure you know [which elements evaluate to `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) so you can apply the right test.

Answer (score 1):

Since php7.4, you can use the null coalescing assignment, so that you can do

```php
$arr = array($one ??= "one?", $two ??= "two ?");
```

See the [docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.null-coalescing-assignment-operator)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but this is the first thing that came to my mind:

```
 echo (!$test) ? "Hello" : $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Null is false in PHP, therefore you can use ternary:

```
alert($test ? $test : 'Hello');
```

Edit:

This also holds for an empty string, <strike>since ternary uses the '===' equality rather than '=='</strike>

And empty or null string is false whether using the '===' or '==' operator. I really should test my answers first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, expanding that notation you supplied means you come up with:

```
if (test) {
    alert(test);
} else {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

So it's just a simple if...else construct. In PHP, you can shorten simple if...else constructs as something called a 'ternary expression':

```
alert($test ? $test : 'Hello');
```

Obviously there is no equivalent to the JS `alert` function in PHP, but the construct is the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
alert((test == null || test == undefined)?'hello':test);
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the very same problem.This is how i solved it:

```
<?php if (empty($row['test'])) {
                    echo "Not Provided";} 
                        else {
                    echo $row['test'];}?></h5></span></span>
              </div>
```

Your value in the database is in variable $test..so if $test row is empty then echo Not Provided