# Operators for set and not empty

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Often I'm using ?? to check variables, but that will pass the left variable even if empty.

I want to express

```
(!empty($b)) ? $b : $c
```

Close is:

```
$b ?: $c
```

Except that will throw a warning if $b is not set.

```
$b ?? $c
```

is the equivalent to isset(), not empty() so if $b is "" that'll be returned.

I'm sure I'm missing something.

I guess want I want is @$b ?: $c  which would express $b as long as it's set and not empty(), otherwise $c, but `@` to hide warnings is such bad form

Comment: I don't think there's a shortcut for `!empty()`.

Comment: How about `($b ?? "") ?: $c`?

Comment: I guess you could suggest some sort of combination of null coalescing Elvis operator -- but I don't like your chances of getting that RFC to pass (`??:`).  I recommend not dwelling on such syntactic sugar -- just use `!empty()`.

Comment: I don't know that it would be very responsible for us to suggest something like `$foo ?? 0 ?: $bar;` when we don't know the exact context of your usage.  https://3v4l.org/k76AZ  There may be times when a falsey/nullish/zero-ish value should not fallback to the rightmost value in the operator chain.  Why is `!empty()` too unattractive?  There may be a better way to refactor your scripting to validate and sanitize your input data (which may be in the form of an array?).

Comment: A [comment to an earlier suggestion of using a null coalesced, shorthand ternary chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-short-ternary-elvis-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator#comment79336772_44992401).

Comment: I agree with mickmackusa: Context is important. I also think we all forget about the fact that we can define our own functions in PHP. Something like: `function neverEmpty($firstChoice, $alternative) { return empty($firstChoice) ? $alternative : $firstChoice; }`.

Comment: I think a dual-operator chain will give your code a smell (not quite as bad as `@$b ?: $c`, but not necessarily a clean way of scripting).  As programming languages have evolved to be more efficient and file size is less a concern and processor performance improved, we need to spend less and less time with micro-optimization and instead endeavor to craft semantic, readable, maintainable code.  Declaring `neverEmpty()` as a helper function will allow you to call it inside of an array function as a callback to concisely sanitize whole payloads. An operator chain cannot be called the same way.

Comment: ...actually, @KIKO, within a helper function `$firstChoice` is always defined, so  it doesn't make sense to use `empty()` in that context. https://3v4l.org/sPgG7

Comment: @mickmackusa Indeed, that's not right. I changed it slightly to: `function neverEmpty(&$firstChoice, $alternative) { return empty($firstChoice) ? $alternative : $firstChoice; }`. See: https://3v4l.org/743sc

Comment: Related: error-suppressed Elvis operator: [`$foo = @$bar ?: $baz;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46989164/2943403) and [`$result = @$var_str ?: "default";`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48917890/2943403) and [`$v = @$v ?: 'default value';`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13507926/2943403) and on CodeReview: [Setting a default value if a variable is empty](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13558/141885)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`($b ?? '') ?: $c`

I compared its behavior to `(!empty($b)) ? $b : $c`, and they seem to be equivalent.

[Tested using onlinephp.io](https://onlinephp.io?s=dY9BC4JAEIXvC_sfXouwChGeM5MIo8NSQnQSCZENI0tpLYjovzfkCh7qXebjMe8NM4uasuHMabVpl7nRBiFSzkCSctyBEBau96qymGYWVgu1iy1v9kpZlH6f9mlmAWecHeubzosS7uBabuCcEc7hPDy8uoQuyhqC7JOBwASuO9KXpn26tOMholVMIb-W9IJBRqKXDP5VUTiK6Dcq-l2SrJNDvFVkvT8%2C&v=8.2.11%2C8.1.24%2C8.0.30%2C7.4.33%2C7.0.33)

Comment: Thank you for testing my suggestion, but the question is about _one_ function or operator that can do this, not two. That's why I used a comment, not an answer. I admit, the question isn't super clear about that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The question doesn't seem to specifically ask for only one function/operator that can perform this task, and as far as I am aware, there _is no_ singular function/operator that can do this.

Comment: Read the question carefully again, I think it does ask for a single function/operator. You're right, there is no possible answer to that question.

Comment: I think this is the closest to the requirements.  Not exactly what I was hoping for, but the closest I'll get with the current version of PHP.  Up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as you can see in the comments, I think that you want to use a single operator/function to select an alternative value when when a variable is empty.

I suggest a custom function for this:

```
function neverEmpty(&$firstChoice, $alternative) {
    return empty($firstChoice) ? $alternative : $firstChoice;
}
```

See: https://3v4l.org/743sc

I think it is obvious what it does. The ampersant before the first function argument means that this argument is [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference).

With thanks to mickmackusa for correcting a bug. He also suggested, and I agree, that we shouldn't try to write the shortest possible code. Code needs to be readable, understandable, and maintainable. A custom function isn't all that much slower than a build-in function. You really cannot tell the difference once you have an application that, for instance, uses a database.

Answer (score 0):

Making a custom function still triggers a warning if the variable is not set.

I suspect, until another more applicable function is made, I'll have to stick with:

!empty( $foo ) ? $foo : $bar

This assumes we already know isset( $bar ) .